# Prevent reboot on each restart

Tags: reboot

how to prevent ubuntu 22.0.4 to reboot each time the computer is restarted. Each time I am powering the laptop down and up again, I am always prompted the GNU interface and hence proceed through a system reboot. I want to know if there is a way of avoiding that in ubuntu. I just started using linux.

Comment: By GNU interface, do you mean [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)?  (*the bootloader, if you have a problem in the future, it's helpful to get around problems, so removing it could mean any problems will be far more severe*).

Comment: It's unclear what you mean - in my world, reboot and restart is basically the same thing - you can't restart a computer without rebooting it. Else, you need to explain more clearly what you want and what you expect. Are you maybe talking about hibernation?

Comment: I suspect you're comparing to Windows which has a "fast start" option, where it hibernates. Hibernate is disabled by default on Ubuntu because it's unreliable on Linux.

Comment: @guiverc I think I have understood now. There is no need going around thr GRUB interface.

Comment: @popey has made it clear. Thanks